# TextBox TextChanged event in ASP.NET, C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am creating a POS screen where barcode scans to a textbox. I want to run the code behind procedure to add barcode related data into the grid as soon as textbox text changed. my textbox is like below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSKU3" ontextchanged="txtSKU3_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ToolTip="SKU" ForeColor="Red" placeholder="SKU" Height="30px" CssClass="form-control input-sm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

my code behind procedure for creating barcode at the moment is like this

```
protected void txtSKU3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string barCode = txtSKU3.Text;
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barCode.Length * 40, 80))
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
        {
            Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 16);
            PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
            SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
            graphics.DrawString("*" + barCode + "*", oFont, blackBrush, point);
        }
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

            Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
            imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
        }
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
    }
}
```

It create the barcode upon lost focus of the textbox but, I need to create it upon scanning the product on a textbox.

Anybody help please.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..  One option could be to use the `KeyDown` event instead of the `TextChanged` event. The `KeyDown` event is triggered when a key is pressed down.  This way, you could listen for the `enter` key to be pressed and then generated the bar code.

```
protected void txtSKU3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        string barCode = txtSKU3.Text;
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = CreateBarcode(barCode);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
    }
}

private System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image CreateBarcode(string barCode)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barCode.Length * 40, 80))
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
        {
            Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 16);
            PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
            SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
            graphics.DrawString("*" + barCode + "*", oFont, blackBrush, point);
        }
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

            Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
            imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
        }
    }
    return imgBarCode;
}
```

then you would also need to change the HTML like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSKU3" onkeydown="txtSKU3_KeyDown" ToolTip="SKU" ForeColor="Red" placeholder="SKU" Height="30px" CssClass="form-control input-sm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Another option would be to add a button next to the text field called "Generate Barcode" that would perform the action. Something like:

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnScan" Text="Scan Barcode" OnClick="btnScan_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" />
```

and the code would then look like this:

```
protected void btnScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string barCode = txtSKU3.Text;
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = CreateBarcode(barCode);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
}
```

In fact, I guess there is nothing stopping you doing both options.  Listening for the `Enter` Key as well as having a `button`.  BTW, I've not tested any of this code and I just re-arranged yours so unsure if it works.

Hope it helps.